# Nginx ignores config file option

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, configuration, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to start nginx with a specific config file as a user process on Ubuntu 14.04. However I'm getting stopped right at the start:

```
$ nginx -c nginx.conf 
nginx: [alert] could not open error log file: open() "/var/log/nginx/error.log" failed (13: Permission denied)
2017/03/30 01:03:46 [emerg] 21805#21805: open() "/usr/share/nginx/nginx.conf" failed (2: No such file or directory)
```

It seems to be continuing to try to open the default config and other files. I see nginx was build with these options:

```
$ nginx -V
nginx version: nginx/1.10.1
built with OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --with-cc-opt='-g -O2 -fPIE -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' --with-ld-opt='-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -fPIE -pie -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now' --prefix=/usr/share/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock --pid-path=/run/nginx.pid --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/scgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi --with-debug --with-pcre-jit --with-ipv6 --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_addition_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_geoip_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_image_filter_module --with-http_v2_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_xslt_module --with-stream --with-stream_ssl_module --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module --with-threads --add-module=/build/nginx-abUnII/nginx-1.10.1/debian/modules/nginx-auth-pam --add-module=/build/nginx-abUnII/nginx-1.10.1/debian/modules/nginx-dav-ext-module --add-module=/build/nginx-abUnII/nginx-1.10.1/debian/modules/nginx-echo --add-module=/build/nginx-abUnII/nginx-1.10.1/debian/modules/nginx-upstream-fair --add-module=/build/nginx-abUnII/nginx-1.10.1/debian/modules/ngx_http_substitutions_filter_module
```

Any idea how I can get nginx to start as a user process with the specified config file?

Obviously I can work around this problem by including the desired config at the system level and starting nginx normally as root and then switching the www-data or another user, but I'd like in this case to be able to run nginx as a user process no different than any other user application to fit my deployment architecture.

Comment: Have you used Google to find suitable articles and questions? For example if you want to listen to a port below 1024 (ie 80 / 443) you need to start Nginx as root http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/134301/why-does-nginx-starts-process-as-root

Comment: definitely not the issue since to hit that error the config file would have had to have loaded, and obviously not trying to use low ports in this scenario

Answer (score 8, accepted):

-c only lets you set config file name/path relative to the "prefix path", which you can set with -p.

Answer (score 1):

You could try passing the complete path to the `-c` option. For example if the nginx.conf file is in your current directory

```
nginx -c ./nginx.conf
```

Comment: i tried that, and also passing an absolute path, but both failed. seemed the problem had to do with the prefix (see suggested answer)